# Update m2m,foreignkey field to model does not work in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Update to the following News model does not work in DRF.(
address is not updated)
The creation works fine.

```
class News (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField()
    group_address = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)
    user_address = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

```
class NewsSerializerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = News.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer
```

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRF does not support updating m2m fields. try overriding the update method of the serializer.

For example:

```
    from rest_framework.fields import empty

    class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
            self.original_data = data
            super().__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            items_dict = self.original_data
            if 'group_address' in items_dict:
                ids = [item['id'] for item in items_dict['group_address']]

                instance_data = instance.group_address
                instance_data.set(ids)

            instance = super().update(validated_data=validated_data, instance=instance)
            instance.save()

            return instance

        class Meta:
            model = News
            fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: thank you for answer
I tried running it immediately but got the following error
`NameError: name 'empty' is not defined`
Therefore, I changed the empty to None and implemented it, but a different error occurred and I can not proceed further
`ids = [item['id'] for item in items_dict['group_address']]TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @reno the error means that items_dict['group_address'] is not a list, but an integer. When updating a m2m field, you should send the values in a list.

Comment: empty comes from:  from rest_framework.fields import empty